# Symfony:new entity error inserting ArrayCollection item

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am not yet able to properly configure associations in Symfony2.  For a one-to-many relationship (many household members to one client) current code appears below.
When the member foreach loop is omitted, the client is added as expected.  The error at present is:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Client#members' that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Member@00000000248e5b80000000004cc2e70f. To
>   solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you
>   cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Member#__toString()' to get a clue.

#### Client Entity snippet

```
namespace Mana\ClientBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Member", mappedBy="client")
    */
    protected $members;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->members = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setMembers(ArrayCollection $members)
    {
        $this->members = $members;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addMember(Member $member)
    {
        $this->members->add($member);
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMember(Member $member)
    {
        $this->members->removeElement($member);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMembers()
    {
        return $this->members;
    }
```

#### Household Entity

```
namespace Mana\ClientBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Member
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="household")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Member
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="members")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="clientId", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
     protected $client;

//--- properties

    public function setClient(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

//  getters, setters
```

#### Controller createAction():

```
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $client  = new Client();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ClientType(), $client);
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($client);
            $em->flush();
            foreach ($client->getMembers() as $member)
            {
                $em->persist($member);
            }
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('client_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental factor to recognize is that Doctrine only acts on changes made to the owning side of a ManyToOne relationship, and the owning side is the entity that contains the ManyToOne clause.  So for the present case, Household is the owning side that needs to be persisted, rather than client. So the key change to the controller was:

```
    $member->setClient($client);
    $em->persist($member);
```

Answer (score 0):

What does "$members" contain?

The error you are getting is that you are basically trying to store some object which has a "client_id" in the database, but isn't being set by your object.

If whatever $members contains has that column, it could be you need to call something like

```
$member->setClient($entity)
```

before you try to flush() them.

Also, just so you know, that error won't be thrown until $em->flush() is actually called, because that's the only time it'll try to insert something in to your database. It's likely it works without the for loop because the $members are never added to client, hence it doesn't try to persist them.

## Update

You shouldn't assign client ID directly. Your first relationship was more correct.

```
// In HouseHold
/**
 *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
 *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="clientId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $client;

public function getClient() { return $this->client; }
public function setClient(Client $client) { $this->client = $client; }
```

Than do $member->setClient($client) instead of setClientId().

As far as Doctrine is concerned, The clientId variable means nothing to it. It is looking for getClientId() on Client.

Comment: I've updated the code above to show a more appropriate unidirectional relationship.  It should also improve clarity.  The constraint error remains.

Comment: The above code is bass-ackwards!  The more I try to figure this out the worse it gets.  But I'm fairly convinced I need a working unidirectional mapping from client (one) to household members (many).  But I keep generating errors and I have not yet found an example I can replicate AND make work.  ARRGGHH!

Comment: Code replaced to latest unidirectional - but still generates error quoted above.

Comment: I just noticed you have @ORM(ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client"). If you have that in your actual code, that wouldn't get processed like that. Though it may just be a typo in your post. Also, I still think you need to specify $member->setClient($entity). The problem seems to be HouseHold's Client object is never set to anything, so it's null, so the ID is null, thus the error.

Comment: Thanks!  I had just discovered my typo yesterday.  I've changed the names a bit, and the error has changed.  I'm getting closer.  Where would the equivalent of $member->setClient() go?

Comment: If what is in your post is your latest code, $member->setClient($client) should go directly above $me->persist in your loop. Also, you can remove the $em->flush() right above the lop. Once flush() will save all of the changes (the one after the loop).

Comment: I've decided to quit trying to learn Symfony.  I have spent more than two weeks trying to get ArrayCollection to function as advertised. Multiple posts here and at Symfony have only brought frustration.  I'm glad to know, though, that others are successful with it.  I just am not in that happy crowd.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
foreach ($client->getMembers() as $member)
        {
            $em->merge($member);
        }
```